# Parsing file in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

i have a file, and i would like to parse it in a structure.
the file looks like this:

```
(0,0) (33,18,109)
(0,1) (33,18,109)
(0,2) (33,21,109)
(0,3) (33,21,112)
(0,4) (33,25,112)
(0,5) (33,32,112)
(1,0) (33,18,109)
(1,1) (35,18,109)
(1,2) (35,21,109)
(1,3) (38,21,112)
```

and my structure look like that

```
data Pixel = Pixel  { point::(Int, Int),
                    color::(Int, Int, Int) } deriving Show
```

I have eard about optparser, but i don't know how to use it
i try something with pattern matching but it doesn't work...

thanks!

Comment: optparse is about parsing command-line options, not text files. You want something more like parsec, or regex-applicative.

Comment: You can post your code even if it does not work, along with the error message. Actually, that makes more sense than posting working code :-)

Comment: Your data format looks pretty inflexible. Actually that makes things easier. You can probably parse it using simple functions such as  `lines`, `words`,  `read`. As for `read`, you might want to have a look at the [TypeApplications](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/type-application) Haskell language extension.

Comment: Something like: `parseColor cstr = read @(Int, Int, Int) cstr`

Answer (score 4):

You could write your own Read instance to parse your data to Pixel:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}


module Main where


import qualified Data.Text as T

data Pixel = Pixel  {
            point::(Int, Int)
        ,   color::(Int, Int, Int)
        } deriving (Show)

instance Read Pixel where
    readsPrec _ pixelRaw =
        let makeMatch = (\(p:c:xs) -> (p,c)) $ words pixelRaw
            point' = read @(Int,Int) $ fst makeMatch
            color' = read @(Int, Int, Int) $ snd makeMatch
        in [(Pixel point' color', "")]


main :: IO ()
main = do
    fileContent <- map ((read @Pixel) . T.unpack) . T.splitOn (T.pack "\n") <$> (T.pack <$> readFile "input.txt")
    mapM_ print fileContent
```

Answer (score 3):

For this particular file format, @ThomasMeyer's solution using `read` is reasonable.  However, if you want to program in Haskell, it's practically mandatory that you learn how to use a monadic parser library like Parsec (or Megaparsec, Attoparsec, etc., or even the base library module `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP`).  This will allow you to write complex, flexible parsers to parse just about anything.

Here's how to write a Parsec parser for your file format.  Start with a few preliminaries, the imports plus your data type definition:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

data Pixel = Pixel
  { point :: (Int, Int)
  , color :: (Int, Int, Int)
  } deriving (Show)
```

Your file contains a list of pixels, so we'll write a parser for that first:

```
file :: Parser [Pixel]
file = many pixel
```

This says that a file can be parsed into a list of pixels `[Pixel]` by  "many" (zero or more) applications of the `pixel` parser.

The `pixel` parser is more complex.  It parses a single line into a `Pixel`:

```
pixel :: Parser Pixel
pixel = Pixel <$> pPoint <* space <*> pColor <* newline
```

This parser is written in so-called "applicative" form, much like a Haskell function call with some extra applicative operators `<$>` and `<*>`.  Specifically, the `Pixel <$>` part of the expression applies the `Pixel` constructor to arguments parsed by parsers: the `pPoint` parser that parses something of the form `(1,2)` and the `pColor` parser that parses something of the form `(1,2,3)`.  We can also intersperse these argument-generating parsers with "extra" parsers that parse additional syntax, like the `space` between the point and color, and the `newline` at the end.  Note the use of `<*` before these "extra" parsers and `<*>` before the argument parser `pColor`.  If you insert extra parentheses to show the order of application of these binary operators, the `<` and `>` characters in the operator point to the parts that get "kept" when calculating the final result:

```
(((Pixel <$> pPoint) <* space) <*> pColor) <* newline
   ^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^      ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^
   keep      keep       drop       keep       drop
```

The final result of applying this parser is:

```
Pixel whatever_is_parsed_by_pPoint whatever_is_parsed_by_pColor
```

The `pPoint` parser parses a pair of integers between parentheses, and I've shown the parts that get "kept" in producing the final result.

```
pPoint :: Parser (Int, Int)
pPoint = (,) <$ char '(' <*> int <* char ',' <*> int <* char ')'
    --   ^^^^                ^^^^                ^^^^
    --   keep                keep                keep
```

The result is `(,) first_parsed_int second_parsed_int` which uses the pair constructor `(,)` to construct a pair of integers.

The `pColor` parser is similar:

```
pColor :: Parser (Int, Int, Int)
pColor = (,,) <$ char '(' <*> int <* char ',' <*> int <* char ',' <*> int <* char ')'
```

The `int` parser parses one or more digit characters into an `Int`:

```
int :: Parser Int
int = read <$> many1 digit
```

The complete program, with a `main` driver, looks like this:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

data Pixel = Pixel
  { point :: (Int, Int)
  , color :: (Int, Int, Int)
  } deriving (Show)

file :: Parser [Pixel]
file = many pixel

pixel :: Parser Pixel
pixel = Pixel <$> pPoint <* space <*> pColor <* newline

pPoint :: Parser (Int, Int)
pPoint = (,) <$ char '(' <*> int <* char ',' <*> int <* char ')'

pColor :: Parser (Int, Int, Int)
pColor = (,,) <$ char '(' <*> int <* char ',' <*> int <* char ',' <*> int <* char ')'

int :: Parser Int
int = read <$> many1 digit

main :: IO ()
main = do
  txt <- getContents
  case parse file "(stdin)" txt of
    Left err -> error $ "bad parse: " ++ show err
    Right ps -> print ps
```

and it parses your input like so:

```
$ runghc PixelParser.hs <pixelparser.in 
[Pixel {point = (0,0), color = (33,18,109)},Pixel {point = (0,1), 
color = (33,18,109)},Pixel {point = (0,2), color = (33,21,109)},
Pixel {point = (0,3), color = (33,21,112)},Pixel {point = (0,4), 
color = (33,25,112)},Pixel {point = (0,5), color = (33,32,112)},
Pixel {point = (1,0), color = (33,18,109)},Pixel {point = (1,1),
color = (35,18,109)},Pixel {point = (1,2), color = (35,21,109)},
Pixel {point = (1,3), color = (38,21,112)}]
```

For some more examples/tutorials, I can recommend:  [Jake Wheat's Intro to Parsing with Parsec in Haskell](http://jakewheat.github.io/intro_to_parsing/), [Two Wrongs / Parser Combinators](https://two-wrongs.com/parser-combinators-parsing-for-haskell-beginners.html) for parsing using `ReadP`, and the ["Using Parsec" chapter of Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html).